# How do you get a data value associated with a specific col,row from a 2-d array in java?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

here is the code I have written in java I think it is right. I am just not sure what to set result to? I want to return the element associated with the specific row column

```
public int getElement(int row,int col){
    int result = 0;
    if(((row>=1) && (row <=rowArray.length))&&((col>=1) && (col <=colArray.length))){
        result = ??
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to implement a sparse 2d array? You could use a Map<Pair<int,int>,int> to do that.

Comment: Ben says: "I want to make linked lists to implement a 2-d matrix." I would wonder, why? Must be a sparse array. But this snippet is not related to linked lists. Hmmm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you have 2 separate array for making a 2d array ?

Your class content should be like :

```
public int array2D[10][15]; // 10 row and 15 col

public int getElementAt(int rowIndex, int colIndex)
{
    int ret;
    if( rowIndex >= 0 && rowIndex < array2D.length && colIndex >= 0 && colIndex < array2D[0].length )
    {
        ret = array2D[rowIndex][colIndex];
    }
    else
    {
        // Throw something according to what you want or exit or special return value
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: I am trying to make a linked list implementing a 2-d matrix. with a linked list for column and one for row

Comment: Even with a linked list, you need a column for every row. You need m x n collections, not 2.

Answer (score 1):

If you just have one row array and one column array then you have something like this

```
  foo bar baz
  sna
  fu
```

but what you really want is something like this

```
  foo bar baz
  sna rah boo
  fu  man chu
```

You'd declare this something like:

```
class MyClass {
  String myArray[][] = new String[3][3];

  MyClass() {
    // assign data into myArray
  }

  String getAt(int i, int j) {
    if ((i >= 0) && (i < myArray.length) &&
        (j >= 0) && (j < myArray[i].length)) {
      return myArray[i][j];
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you actually have a non-rectangular array, then you will have to check rowArray[row].length instead of colArray.length.

Then you will set result = rowArray[row][col];

But since you did not actually disclose the rowArray declaration and the colArray declaration, we all are just guessing.

Comment: public MatrixEntry[] rowArray;
    
     { rowArray = null; 

} 

public MatrixEntry[] colArray;
    
    { colArray = null; 

} 

I want to make linked lists to implement a 2-d matrix. Is this possible using two one dimensional arrays? or do I need to use a 2-d array?

Answer (score 0):

First, arrays are indexed from 0 not 1. Typical idiom is something like "if ( row >= 0 && row < rowArray.length ) { ... }".

Also, for such simple expressions you don't need so many parenthesis; it overly complicates the expression. Keep it simple. If you really want to you could group each individual comparison, but I probably wouldn't.

Finally, your code would look like:

```
public int getElement(int row, int col) {
   int result = 0;
   if ((row >= 0) && (row < rowArray.length) &&
       (col >= 0) && (col < colArray.length)) {
      result = rowArray[row][col];
   }
   return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Reading your comments, im not sure what exactly you want.
Do you want something like:
 List1:  ItemA, ItemB, ItemC ...
 List2:  ItemD ...
 List3:  ItemE, ItemF ..

if so, i would suggest using an Array (1-dimension) of LinkedLists.
That way, the array index represent the row, and the list represent the columns in that row